# Blogspot : Limit posts on label (json)

Tags: json, label, posts, limits, blogspot

In blogspot - I found a script about this function. But I only have 25 posts per label, I want more posts such as 100 or 200 posts per label.

This is script

```
<div class='rbbox'>
    <h7>CÁC CHAP TRONG BỘ TRUYỆN</h7>
    <div id='albri'/>
    <script type='text/javascript'> var homeUrl3 = "
        <data:blog.homepageUrl/>"; var maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel; var maxNumberOfLabels; maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel = 100; maxNumberOfLabels = 1; function listEntries10(json) { var ul = document.createElement('ul'); var maxPosts = (json.feed.entry.length <= maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel) ? json.feed.entry.length : maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel; for (var i = 0; i < maxPosts; i++) { var entry = json.feed.entry[i]; var alturl; for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) { if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') { alturl = entry.link[k].href; break; } } var li = document.createElement('li'); var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href = alturl; if(a.href!=location.href) { var txt = document.createTextNode(entry.title.$t); a.appendChild(txt); li.appendChild(a); ul.appendChild(li); } } for (var l = 0; l < json.feed.link.length; l++) { if (json.feed.link[l].rel == 'alternate') { var raw = json.feed.link[l].href; var label = raw.substr(homeUrl3.length+13); var k; for (k=0; k
        <100; k++) label = label.replace("%20", " "); var txt = document.createTextNode(label); var h = document.createElement('b'); h.appendChild(txt); var div1 = document.createElement('div'); div1.appendChild(h); div1.appendChild(ul); document.getElementById('albri').appendChild(div1); } } } function search10(query, label) { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.setAttribute('src', query + 'feeds/posts/default/-/' + label + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=listEntries10'); script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script); } var labelArray = new Array(); var numLabel = 0; 
            <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
                <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'> textLabel = "
                    <data:label.name/>"; var test = 0; for (var i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++) if (labelArray[i] == textLabel) test = 1; if (test == 0) { labelArray.push(textLabel); var maxLabels = (labelArray.length <= maxNumberOfLabels) ? labelArray.length : maxNumberOfLabels; if (numLabel < maxLabels) { search10(homeUrl3, textLabel); numLabel++; } } 
                </b:loop>
            </b:loop>
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>RelPost();</script>
    </div>
```

I changed `maxNumberOfPostsPerLabel = 100`; but it's still display only 25 posts, Can someone help me about this ? I really need to show more posts :(

[image: Image for display on web:]

Here is my web link : http://manga.mystown.com/2015/08/juji-itou-horror-collection-chap-39.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please be a bit more clear about what you are asking and can you please format your code so that it's readable.

Comment: Thanks for reply e4c5. I have just format this code above. I need more posts related on per label. But this code is only give me <= 25posts. I write english so bad, sorry about this.

Comment: In my link :

http://manga.mystown.com/2015/08/juji-itou-horror-collection-chap-39.html

On this line : CÁC CHAP TRONG BỘ TRUYỆN

I want it shows 100 posts. But It's only show 25 posts, Can you understand me :( 

In that link, it shows Chap 20 - 44, It doesn't show Chap 1 - 20. I had already 44 chaps in my website